# How do I call a stored procedure from Magento code?

Tags: magento-1.9, database

I have a stored procedure, called "myprocedure". How can I call it from Magento?

I tried:

```
$resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
$readConnection = $resource->getConnection('core_read');
$query = 'CALL myprocedure()';
$results = $readConnection->fetchAll($query);
var_dump($results);
```

This gives me a PDO error, whats wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: this might lead you in the right direction: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6282391/magento-create-stored-procedure

Comment: Thanks, but this is not for calling it, but for the creation. I need to actually call it from an observer.

Comment: what if you use `$readConnection->exec($query)` instead of `fetchAll`

Comment: @pzirkind. Please write you comment as an answer so the OP can accept it.

Answer (score 6):

Try using `prepare` and `execute` instead:

```
$resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
$readConnection = $resource->getConnection('core_read');
$query = 'CALL myprocedure()';
$sql   = $readConnection->prepare($query);
$sql->execute();
$data  = $sql->fetchAll();
```

Answer (score 3):

It seems that to execute stored procedures you would need to use the following code:

```
$resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
$readConnection = $resource->getConnection('core_read');
$query = 'CALL myprocedure()';
$results = $readConnection->exec($query); // this is the line that needs changing (use exec)
```

In other words use `exec()` instead of `fetchAll()`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use parameters in and out then you have to run like this to get output

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$resource = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection');
$connection = $resource->getConnection();
$connection->query("CALL SomeStoredProcedure($someInParameter1, $someInParameter2, @someOutParameter)"); 
$results = $connection->query("SELECT @someOutParameter");
```